# What are the restrictions on "database-name" when attaching a database using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any information otherwise, assume it's an SQL identifier. SQLite reserves the names `main` and `temp`, but almost anything else can be used if properly quoted. Still, I'd recommend avoiding SQL keywords and such, if just to keep the confusion quota down. (Database names are arbitrary, and do not need to correlate with the name of the file containing them.)

Comment: Also note the database name ":memory:" is used for in-memory databases, so I'm not sure what would happen if you used that as the database-name alias.